# is it possible, to get a renderd HTML page as graphic

Tags: html, printing, converters

My customer has a nice (meal-) menu for his restaurant in internet; he also manages his dayly and weekly specials with a small application via internet, entering only name of food (description) and price.
Now he wants to print his pages to a (paper) menu card. but how he (I) tried, the printout is always poor, because the html page was not designed for printing. Graphics (eg. backgrounds) are not printed, shifted, on one extra page and so on.

So my idea was to get the page as graphic and print it - after small corrections - via a graphics programm.

Is that possible, or are there ways to control printout better, than the stadard printig engines of browsers?

He wants a WYSIWYG and not "what you get is what the browser thinks you want to see"

other ideas are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wkhtmltoimage ? http://wkhtmltopdf.org/